# how many users have the same occurrences of strings value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know how many users have the same  occurrences of strings value
the data is in python dataframe type, the order of the values doesn't matter and should be counted once (x-y is the same as y-x)

```
user_id    value
1            x
1            y   
2            x
2            y
2            z   
3            x
3            z

Combination   #of user
x-y             2
x-z             2
y-z             1
```

Comment: Please post what you have already tried and errors if found so people can help you.

Comment: You should probably rephrase the question and make it more readable - it is pretty un-understandable

Answer (score 2):

Create combinations per groups, then flatten values by `chain.from_iterable` and count by `Counter`:

```
from  itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import Counter

s = df.groupby('user_id')['value'].apply(lambda x: list(map( '-'.join, combinations(x, 2))))
#if necessary sorted combinations
#s = (df.groupby('user_id')['value']
#       .apply(lambda x: ['-'.join(sorted(y)) for y in combinations(x, 2)]))

d = Counter(chain.from_iterable(s))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Combination': list(d.keys()),
                   'user':list(d.values())})
print (df)
  Combination  user
0         x-y     2
1         x-z     2
2         y-z     1
```